# Column Headers Repeated Into Rows of Table MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, ado

I have an Excel file linked to MS SQL Server through ADO connections. Within this file I can update data in the database. IE each row in Excel is a row in SQL Server.

Everything works great, except for some reason certain column headers in my SQL Server get written into every row of data and I'm not sure why. For example, my column header is `Construction Date`. What I see in every row of that column is `construction date`.

This problem seems to only occur from one of the Excel files I have. I have multiple Excel files accessing the same table in SQL Server but the only fields that seem to have this problem are the ones in that specific Excel file. The code is the same across all Excel files, the only difference is the users. That leaves me to assume the problem is because Excel crashes.

Anyone know why this occurs?

Comment: Does the problem spreadsheet use `select 'Construction Date'` rather than `select [Construction Date]`?

Comment: No it uses the Excel Connection Wizard to SQL Server so I don't hard code the select statement

Answer (score 0):

There is no select statement. The excel data is just a linked table to SQL server. The update statement is based on primary keys and is hard coded. The data that has changed is stored on a seperate tab and the update runs when you click a button.